# Is Samsung's Facial Recognition secure on Galaxy A50?

Tags: samsung, security, face-unlock

Cheap Samsung phones have facial recognition functionality. The settings application states that if the "Faster recognition" option is enabled, "A video or image could be recognized as your face".

So, if I disable faster recognition my phone cannot be fooled by image/video? How can a simple camera decide whether it sees a real person or a photo/video?

Comment: Facial recognition in general is vulnerable to spoofing no matter what. It's all about how accurately a physical face can be constructed. Software based solutions make it more vulnerable because they don't have 3D data. An AI model can be trained to distinguish between a face in image/video and a real face. These things add little resistance against spoofing attacks but they don't make it impractical.